# Multiple REST service controls on XPage

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I need to provide a number of web services to supply data from a Notes application to an external website.

I have created an XAgent with multiple custom REST service controls. Each control has its own "pathInfo" property and code defined in "doGet" to return a JSON object containing the relevant data required by the website.

This all works well and the correct data is returned by calls to each web service. However, having added some debug messages to each "doGet" I see that **all** services on the XPage are being triggered by a call to any one of them.

I have a couple of additional REST service controls on the same XPage with code defined in "doPost", used by the website to create records in the Notes database. This also works well with the desired results, but the debug messages show that when a call to one of these services is made all of the "get" services are also triggered.

Any idea what is going on here? I could create a separate XAgent for each REST service control, but it seems overkill if it's not necessary.

UPDATE

Here is a cut down version of the XPage with just two of the "get" services. It doesn't matter which of these services is called, the log messages show that getHospitals is triggered first followed by getCustomerTypes. However, the correct resultset is always returned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
rendered="false">

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var vwSettings:NotesView = database.getView("vwSettings");
var docSettings:NotesDocument = vwSettings.getFirstDocument();
sessionScope.put("App_DbPath", docSettings.getItemValueString("App_DbPath"));
sessionScope.put("WR_DbPath", docSettings.getItemValueString("WR_DbPath"));
sessionScope.put("logActivity", true);}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/Utils.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="/OpenLogXPages.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="getHospitals">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:customRestService contentType="application/json"
            requestContentType="application/json" requestVar="hospital">
            <xe:this.doGet><![CDATA[${javascript:try {
if (sessionScope.logActivity == true) {
    log.logEvent("getHospitals");
}

var dbApp:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(), sessionScope.App_DbPath);

var vwHospitals:NotesView = dbApp.getView("vhospitals.by.name");
var vecHospitals:NotesViewEntryCollection = vwHospitals.getAllEntries();

var eHospital:NotesViewEntry = vecHospitals.getFirstEntry()

var arrHospitals = new Array();

while (eHospital != null) {
    var hospital = {};
    hospital["Name"] = eHospital.getColumnValues()[0];
    hospital["HCode"] = eHospital.getColumnValues()[1];

    arrHospitals.push(hospital);

    eHospital = vecHospitals.getNextEntry(eHospital);
}

log.logEvent("getHospitals - END");

return toJson(arrHospitals);

} catch(e) {
   log.logError(e.toString());
}}]]></xe:this.doGet>


        </xe:customRestService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>

<xe:restService id="restService2" pathInfo="getCustomerTypes">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:customRestService contentType="application/json"
            requestContentType="application/json">
            <xe:this.doGet><![CDATA[${javascript:try {
if (sessionScope.logActivity == true) {
    log.logEvent("getCustomerTypes");
}

var dbApp:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(), sessionScope.App_DbPath);

var vw:NotesView = dbApp.getView("vkeywords");
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntriesByKey("Customer Type");

var e:NotesViewEntry = vec.getFirstEntry()

var arrItems = new Array();

while (e != null) {
    var item = {};
    item["CustomerType"] = e.getColumnValues()[1];

    arrItems.push(item);

    e = vec.getNextEntry(e);
}

log.logEvent("getCustomerTypes - END");

return toJson(arrItems);

} catch(e) {
    log.logError(e.toString());
}}]]></xe:this.doGet>


        </xe:customRestService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

And the services are called using

```
https://<<domain name>>/<<path name>>/ws.nsf/test.xsp/getHospitals
```

and

```
https://<<domain name>>/<<path name>>/ws.nsf/test.xsp/getCustomerTypes
```

Comment: Hi Martin, any chance you could include some details e.g. xsp markup? rest service code, the url that is being used for get request

Comment: Martin: I recommend that you remove the beforePageLoad code and add it to a function in one of the server side javascript libraries. Then call that function from the doGet routines of the rest services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the "doGet" properties were set to "compute on page load" rather than "compute dynamically". Not sure how that crept in - probably a copy and paste error.

Comment: ah that explains it! I was curious about that behavior. don't forget to mark this question answered so that it doesn't sit around as unanswered forever